# Configuring DateTimeDropdown year selection

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have a registration form with a `DateTimeDropdown` claim type to allow a user to select their date of birth.

This is the policy configuration of the claim:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="dateOfBirth">
    <DisplayName>Date of birth</DisplayName>
    <DataType>date</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Please select your birth date</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

And how it renders on the form:

[image]

The `Year` selection gives a range starting at 1900 and goes up to 2050.

Is there any custom policy configuration to alter, limit, or reorder the values present in this dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible by using the PredicateValidations. See [date range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/predicates#configure-a-date-range)

1. With the Predicates and PredicateValidations elements you can control the minimum and maximum date values of the UserInputType by using a DateTimeDropdown

   `<Predicates>
     <Predicate Id="DateRange" Method="IsDateRange" HelpText="The date must be between 01-01-1980 and today.">
       <Parameters>
         <Parameter Id="Minimum">1980-01-01</Parameter>
         <Parameter Id="Maximum">Today</Parameter>
       </Parameters>
     </Predicate>
   </Predicates>`

   2. Add a PredicateValidation with a reference to the DateRange predicate.

      `<PredicateValidations>
      <PredicateValidation Id="CustomDateRange">
      <PredicateGroups>
        <PredicateGroup Id="DateRangeGroup">
          <PredicateReferences>
            <PredicateReference Id="DateRange" />
          </PredicateReferences>
        </PredicateGroup>
      </PredicateGroups>
      </PredicateValidation>
      </PredicateValidations>`
   3. In your claim type, add PredicateValidationReference element and specify the identifier as CustomDateRange.

   `<ClaimType Id="dateOfBirth">
     <DisplayName>Date of Birth</DisplayName>
     <DataType>date</DataType>
     <AdminHelpText>The user's date of birth.</AdminHelpText>
     <UserHelpText>Your date of birth.</UserHelpText>
     <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
     <PredicateValidationReference Id="CustomDateRange" />
   </ClaimType>`

Comment: Would be nice to have ```<Parameter Id="Maximum">Today.AddYears(-18)</Parameter>``` support here!